# substitute characters in a string in all possible combinations

Tags: bash, combinations, substitution

### Character substitution in all possible combinations

I have string as follows,

```
XGXXGXXGGXXGXXGX
```

I would like to iteratively substitute X's for either one, two, three or four . (dots) if they satisfy the following conditions,

1. Substitution in "XGGX" is not allowed.
2. More than two substitutions on either side of "XGGX" disallowed.
3. Substitutions that result in ".G." are disallowed.

Really appreciate any help. I tried awk splitting, assigning each character to array and then sed for substitution but it doesn't output as intended.

The output should look like,

```
.GXXGXXGGXXGXXGX
.GX.GXXGGXXGXXGX
.GX.GXXGGXXGX.GX
```

and so on.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesBrown: I have tried to rephrase. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I there one and only one `XGGX` in the string? Can the pattern `XGGX(GGX)*` appear in the string?

Comment: @Fravadona: Yes it can.

Comment: Given your rules and sample input, your strings seem to be composed of only a few `XGX` and a single `XGGX`. If your data can contain other things than that then you should post an example more representative of it. Try passing your data through `sed -E 's/(XGGX|XGX|.)/\1 /g'` and check if there's any single character that appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I have made a file, containing all combinations of a, b and c, and at the end I added some cases where not all of those letters are present:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
aabb
ccdd
ddee
```

In order to get the lines which contain all combinations, I just did the following:

```
cat test.txt | grep "a" | grep "b" | grep "c" | grep -o "[abc]*"
```

This means:

- `| grep "a" | grep "b" | grep "c"` : only show lines which contain AND 'a' AND 'b' AND 'c'
- `grep -o "[abc]*"` : show the possible combinations.

The result is as follows:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Sorry of the poor drafting of question. I have edited the original post to clarify it. Hopefully it makes sense now!